# What does .align in ARM architecture

Tags: assembly, arm, gnu-assembler

I am new to assembly level coding so I am bit confused what .align does. I have looked up what it does in many places.https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/projects/raspberrypi/tutorials/os/ok05.html in this link a description on .align is given in red box on the right hand side of the page. Another place i refereed was http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0489c/Babecdje.html. What does it mean for a address to be 4 bytes aligned or 8 bytes aligned ?

If I use the following instructions in my code

```
.align 4
pattern:
```

Then does mean the address assigned to pattern will be of the form 4*n or 16*n ( 2^4 = 16).

Comment: You forgot to mention which assembler program you are using. It can be either of the two possibilities you mentioned, depending on the assembler. Consult the appropriate manual, don't just google randomly ;)

Comment: I use arm-linux-gnueabi-as command for compiling assembly codes.

Comment: Then see the [gnu as manual](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.20/as/Align.html). It says you will get `2^n` alignment on `arm`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An address is said to be "*n*-bytes aligned" if it's evenly divisible by *n*.

This can also be expressed as "an address is 2<sup>*m*</sup>-bytes aligned if its rightmost *m* bits are all zero".

Alignment is very common a requirement, i.e. the hardware requires as part of its programming model that certain alignment requirements are always respected. Failure to do so might lead to a hard fault, i.e. the processor stops.